# JdbcTemplate insert success but no rows in database

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbctemplate

This question was asked a couple of years ago, but the answer didn't work for me.  I have added the suggested annotations to the config and to the dao. I am sure that Template is actually connecting to the DB because I was getting appropriate errors when I had a column too small. The update call is doing a single row insert and it is returning 1 with no exceptions.  Yet, when I check the database there is no data in it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.XXX.query.repository")
public class SqlConfig {
  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Bean
  public DataSource getDatasource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    datasource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("sql-datasource.driverClassName"));
    datasource.setUrl(env.getProperty("sql-datasource.url"));
    datasource.setUsername(env.getProperty("sql-datasource.username"));
    datasource.setPassword(env.getProperty("sql-datasource.password"));

    return datasource;
  }

  @Bean
  public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(getDatasource());
  }
```

**DAO:**

```
@Repository
public class SqlRepositoryImpl implements SqlRepository {

  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate template;

<snip>

  @Transactional
  @Override
  public void addOrder(String foo, String bar, String bat, String cat) {

    int i;
    try {
      // we may already have this data
      System.out.println("here");
      i = template.update(
        "insert into someTable "
          + "(A, B, C, D)"
          + " values (?,?,?,?)",
        foo, bar, bat, cat);
    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
      checkForDupeKey(ex);
    }

<snip>
```

Comment: are you sure that there is nothing in the DB? Using `@Transactional` should be fine. Can you check the log of the database? Is this the whole code or are you maybe deleting all data somewhere?

Comment: Yes - you're right. There was a stupid mistake in the <snip> area that threw an exception and unwound the transaction. For some reason that exception never bubbled to the surface so I wasn't aware of it until I stepped through everything one line at a time. My apologies for wasting people's time.

Answer (score 1):

There was a stupid mistake in the  area that threw an exception and unwound the transaction. For some reason that exception never bubbled to the surface so I wasn't aware of it until I stepped through everything one line at a time. My apologies for wasting people's time.